# Remember mutableStateOf custom class in Android Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I created a android compose component and to avoid multiple params, it takes only one parameter : an object

Here is my component :

```
@Composable
fun ValidationButton(validationButtonModel: ValidationButtonModel)
```

My object :

```
import android.os.Parcelable
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize

@Parcelize
data class ValidationButtonModel(
    var title: Int,
    var contentDescription: Int,
    var rfidReadingStarted: Boolean,
    var progression: Float,
    var read: Int,
    var expected: Int,
) : Parcelable
```

Here is how i define it to compose for being remember between recomposition AND being a state (launch recomposition when change) :

```
val validationButtonModelState by rememberSaveable() {
        mutableStateOf(
            ValidationButtonModel(
                R.string.common_validate,
                R.string.common_contentDescription,
                true,
                0.1f,
                7,
                10
            )
        )
    }
```

But if i try to update it with for example this :

```
ValidationButton(
                    validationButtonModelState,
                )

Button(onClick = 
          {
                 validationButtonModelState.rfidReadingStarted = true
                 if (validationButtonModelState.progression < 1.0f) {
                    validationButtonModelState.progression += 0.1f
                    validationButtonModelState.read += 1
                 }
          }, content = {
              Text("INCREMENT")
            })
```

There is no re composition.

I try to add a Saver but doesn't work too :

```
val validationButtonModelSaver = listSaver<ValidationButtonModel, Any>(
    save = { listOf(it.rfidReadingStarted, it.read, it.progression, it.expected, it.title, it.contentDescription) },
    restore = { ValidationButtonModel(rfidReadingStarted = it[0] as Boolean, read = it[1] as Int, progression = it[2] as Float, expected = it[4] as Int, title = it[5] as Int, contentDescription = it[6] as Int)}
)

val validationButtonModelState by rememberSaveable(validationButtonModelSaver) {
        mutableStateOf(
            ValidationButtonModel(
                R.string.common_validate,
                R.string.common_contentDescription,
                true,
                0.1f,
                7,
                10
            )
        )
    }
```

Am i missing something ? Following this : https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#parcelize
It should works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only change the fields inside your model, `mutableStateOf(ModValidationButtonModel)` it won't work, as you are still updating your old instance. You need to pass in a new instance of your model effectively.

try

`validationButtonModelState = ModValidationButtonModel()`

or since it is a data class you can also do

```kotlin
validationButtonModelState = validationButtonModelState.copy(
    read = validationButtonModelState.read+1
)
```