# Jetpack Compose - Why remembered custom object not holding changes after recomposition

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a custom object with a boolean value that I want to observe on my screen to change my layout.

Example:

```
data class Book(isFavorited: Boolean)


@Composable 
fun ShowBook(book: Book, onConfirm: (Book) -> Unit){
   val bookState = remember { mutableStateOf(book) }

   //just an example
   val color = if(bookState.value.isFavorited) Color.Red else Color.White

   //changing the value of isFavorited, should do recomposition?
   Button(onClick { bookState.value.isFavorited = true }){
     Text("add to fav")
   }

   Button(onClick { bookState.value.isFavorited = false }){
     Text("remove from fav")
   }

   Button(onClick { onConfirm.invoke(bookState.value) }){
     Text("Confirm")
   }       
 }
```

If I press the **"add to fav"** button and set to my **bookState** a *true* value for *isFavorited*, and after that I press "**Confirm**", the value that I'll receive is still *false* (default value).

Does Anyone know what's happening?

Because I through that changing the bookState attributions it should recompose and set the correct value to the object.

Comment: Answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72559402/17787605

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a couple of improvements in your code... It should work now.

In order to perform a recomposition, you must have to create a new instance of the object. In the code below this is done by calling the `copy` function just changing the params that you want (in case the class has more fields).

```
data class Book(val isFavorited: Boolean)

@Composable
fun ShowBook(book: Book, onConfirm: (Book) -> Unit) {
    // using "by" to avoid use the ".value" everywhere
    var bookState by remember { mutableStateOf(book) }

    // just an example
    val color = if (bookState.isFavorited) Color.Red else Color.White

    // changing the value of isFavorited, should do recomposition?
    Button(onClick = { bookState = bookState.copy(isFavorited = true) }){
        Text("add to fav")
    }

    Button(onClick = { bookState = bookState.copy(isFavorited = false) }){
        Text("remove from fav")
    }
    // You don't need the "invoke" here. 
    // It can be useful if the lambda is nullable:
    // onConfirm?.invoke(bookState)
    Button(onClick = { onConfirm(bookState) }){
        Text("Confirm")
    }
}
```

Comment: That's it. Copy did the trick. I didn't notice I was updating an old instance

Comment: Is that Compose bug with using bookState.copy(isFavorited = false) instead of bookState.value.isFavorited ?
As for me it's not clear why is that

Comment: No, it's not a bug. Compose must be aware of a state changing has been made. When you call bookState.value.isFavorited = true (for instance) you're changing a property of the object currently assigned as the component state, but Compose will not be aware of that change. Assigning a new object to the component's state will notify Compose that the state has changed, since it's a new instance of the object.

Answer (score 3):

So, if you want to have Book class as holder of state you could do it like this:

```
data class Book(val isSelected: MutableState<Boolean> = mutableStateOf(true))
```

and usage would be:

```
  val book = remember { Book() }
  val color = if (book.isSelected.value) Color.Red else Color.White
```

Changes of fields that do not wrap values inside MutableState wont trigger recompositing.